# Parallel query worker thread was involved in a deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, parallel-processing, deadlock

I run an SQL Server Trace to track some deadlocks issues and I was hit on the head with this comment `Parallel query worker thread was involved in a deadlock` as a reason for the deadlock.

[image]

**Q1:** Does this means that the same query is deadlocking it self? The query execution plan shows some parallelism cases.

**Q2:** What are the possible ways to "force" SQL Server not to use parallelism or at least to avoid using it as much as possible?

Comment: Lookup MAXDOP in Books On Line

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Q1:** No. This just means that the deadlock involves an Exchange operator. On the client side you'll get the error "Transaction (Process ID n) was deadlocked on {thread | **communication buffer**} resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim."

These kind of deadlock will always include two or more processes and will always include a lock resource.

[Here is a repro](http://sqlindian.com/2012/07/06/deadlock-due-to-parallelism/) for this scenario. In most cases, having the correct index will resolve this issue.

When a process deadlock with itself (very rare with latest builds) it's called Intra-Query Parallelism deadlock and you will get an error like "Msg 8650, Level 13, State 1, Line 1 Intra-query parallelism caused your server command (process ID n) to deadlock. Rerun the query without intra-query parallelism by using the query hint option (maxdop 1)." See [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2008/09/24/today-s-annoyingly-unwieldy-term-intra-query-parallel-thread-deadlocks.aspx) for details.

**Q2:** Refer to the links Denis provided.

Comment: Dead repro link. Can you expand on what was in the link?

Comment: I believe that the page mentioned above formerly at http://sqlindian.com/2012/07/06/deadlock-due-to-parallelism/ was moved to https://readuncommitted.com/2012/07/06/deadlock-due-to-parallelism/

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Understanding and Using Parallelism in SQL Server](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-and-using-parallelism-in-sql-server/)

You also want to take a look at using MAXDOP as a query hint

Sometimes all you need is an index, see [Fix Execution Plan showing Parallelism](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/fix-execution-plan-showing-parallelism)