# SQL Deadlocks - Why

Tags: sql-server

Not knowing to much on SQL, but my web app seems to be throwing more errors like so like

```
Exception: System.Data.Entity
An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the inner exception for details.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Transaction (Process ID 68) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

What would the root cause of these errors?

Comment: Have you read the answer to [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/49538/7257)? Does it help? How about the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13839088/1048425)?

Comment: Can you please post the sql which is causing the errors? There are many issues which can cause a deadlock including/ badly written transactions(race conditions). Missing/fragmented index's causing lock escalations.

Comment: Use " exec sp_who2 " to find dead lock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query to find the deadlock historic (with queries) :

```
SELECT CAST(xet.target_data as XMl) as xe_content
FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS xet
join sys.dm_xe_sessions AS xes ON xes.address=xet.event_session_address
WHERE xes.name='system_health'
```

You seem to work with EntityFramework (`System.Data.Entity`). If you want to catch your transaction exception in your code, here is a way to know if you've encountered a deadlock exception. You can then do the specific treatment (run anyway the transaction, ...)

```
if (_exception != null)
{
  if (_exception is EntityCommandExecutionException || _exception is UpdateException)
  {
    if (_exception.InnerException != null)
    {
      if (_exception.InnerException is SqlException)
      {
        if (((SqlException)_exception.InnerException).Number == 1205)
        {
          //This is a deadlock exception via EntityFramework
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```